# implementing local storage in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am creating a challenge tracking app in React. I would like to, after clicking on the challenge button and approving it, be able to add it and save it to the local storage (as a value to save the name of the chosen challenge) and later to print it in the dashboard.

Could anyone please help me with that.

I have 3 classes I am working now and will paste them below.

ChooseChallenge.js

```js
function Challange() {
  const [isPopped, setPop] = useState(false);

  const pop = () => {
    setPop(!isPopped);
  };
 

  return (
    //Fragments
    <>
      {isPopped && <Dialog />}
      <div className="chooseChallenge">
        {/* <Leaf/> */}
        <h1 className="newchallenge">New Challange</h1>
        <hr />
        <div className="challanges">
          <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={pop}>
            Eat Vegetarian (31days)
          </button>
          <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={pop}>
            Take the bike to work (14days)
          </button>
          <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={pop}>
            Recycle your plastic bottles (31days)
          </button>
          <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={pop} >
            Use public transport to commute (31days)
          </button>
          <button className="challangeBtn" onClick={pop}>
            Don't fly an airplane (365days)
          </button>
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default Challange;
```

Dialog.js

```js
function Dialog (){
    
    const [isOpen, setOpennes] = useState(true);

    const Close = () => {
        setOpennes(false);
    }
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
        localStorage.getItem('challengeName') || ''
      );
     
      React.useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('challengeName', value);
      }, [value]);
     
      const onChange = event => setValue(event.target.value);

        return(
            <div className={isOpen ? 'dialogBox' : 'dialogHide'}>
                <h3 id="header">Do you accept the challange?</h3>
            <div className="approvalButtons">
            <button className= "approvalButton" onClick = {Close} value={value} onChange={onChange}> Approve </button>
            <button className= "approvalButton" onClick = {Close}> Decline </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          
        )
    }

export default Dialog;
```

Dashboard.js

```js
export default function Dashboard() {
  // const challengelist = document.querySelector('#challange-list')
  const [challs, setChalls] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      var challs = [];
      await database
        .collection("Challenges")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            challs.push(doc.data().ChallengeName);
          });
        });
      setChalls(challs);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Dashboard">
      <Header />
      <div className="circle">
        <img id="leafpicture" src={leafpic} alt="eco-picture" />
        <div className="textIn">
          <h1> You saved </h1>
          <h5>0.00 CO2</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul id="challange-list">
          {challs.map((ch) => (
            <li key={ch}>{ch}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="progressbar">
        <h3>Track your challenges!</h3>
        {testData.map((item, idx) => (
          <ProgressBar
            key={idx}
            bgcolor={item.bgcolor}
            completed={item.completed}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <br />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Right now if you accept a challenge it does not add it to the local storage

Comment: Did you debug that 'value' is not empty?

Comment: its empty but I am not sure why

Comment: why button has value attribute? Also nowhere value is getting changed

Comment: You need to add some data-attribute on the button, something like data-id, not value attribute on the button.

Answer (score 0):

on dialog.js the value of the button starts with an empty string and this value never changes, so you are always storing and empty string.